# how to resolve the issue of [W NNPACK.cpp:79] Could not initialize NNPACK! Reason: Unsupported hardware

Tags: pytorch, torch, yolov5

I am trying to predict image classes using yolov5 model in m1 chip

while loading and calling the model, i am getting this error

- tried these sources: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/bug-w-nnpack-cpp-80-could-not-initialize-nnpack-reason-unsupported-hardware/107518 but not able to set USE_NNPACK=0 while rebuilding torch

Comment: Could you clarify - what prevented you from setting `USE_NNPACK=0` while rebuilding torch. What happened when you did that? Can you provide the command that you used to build torch?